# jQuery.ajax и ответ с сервера

Tags: jquery, ajax, сервер

Вообщем есть сайт к нему написано api и ajax кидается запрос в таком виде: `http://site.com/api/template/6` и получает ответ, всё хорошо, всё стабильно, после для сайта написали другое api и тут начались проблемы, абсолютно такой же запрос только на другой сервер через браузер ответы получаю, через postmen ответы получаю, но при отправке с сайта запроса методом ajax, jQuery выдаёт ошибку с надписью: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`
Единственно чем различаются данные api, это тем что один на Ubuntu, а второй на Microsoft-IIS/10, может ли быть проблема падения ajax именно в этом??

Comment: другой сервер на другом домене?

Comment: читайте про кросс-доменные аякс запросы, если домены разные, и выставляйте на втором сервере соответствующие заголовки ответа.